# When to close result channel in Worker Pool concurrency pattern?

Tags: go, concurrency

I am trying to understand how concurrency in golang works for that I am trying to process a large JSON file in batches but I am not sure when should I close my channel. Below is the code,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
   "os"
   "time"
)

type Order struct {
    Recipe   string         `json:"recipe"`
    PostCode string         `json:"postcode"`
    Delivery TimeWithFormat `json:"delivery"`
}

type TimeWithFormat struct {
    WeekDay   string
    StartTime time.Time
    EndTime   time.Time
    Valid   bool
}

func main() {
 input, err := os.Open("test.json")
 if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
 }

concurrency := 20
inGest := make(chan []Order)
ret := make(chan map[string]int)

for x := 0; x < concurrency; x++ {
    go processRecipesWorker(inGest, ret)
}

go ParseInMemory(input, inGest)

finalMap := make(map[string]int)
for v := range ret {
    // Combine all incoming results
    for recipe, occurrence := range v {
        if v, ok := finalMap[recipe]; ok {
            finalMap[recipe] = occurrence + v
        } else {
            finalMap[recipe] = occurrence
        }
    }
}

 //Further processing on finalMap

}

func ParseInMemory(input *os.File, ingest chan []Order) {
 data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(input)
 var orders []Order

 if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &orders); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err.Error())
}

batch := 100000
for i := 0; i < len(orders); i += batch {
    j := i + batch
    if j > len(orders) {
        j = len(orders)
    }
    ingest <- orders[i:j]
 }
 close(ingest)
}

func processRecipesWorker(in <-chan []helpers.Order, r chan map[string]int) {
 result := make(map[string]int)
 for _, order := range <-in {
    if v, ok := result[order.Recipe]; ok {
        result[order.Recipe] = v + 1
    } else {
        result[order.Recipe] = 1
    }
 }
 r <- result
}
```

I am new to golang and concurrency if there are changes needed in my code please let me know.

Feel free to comment in case of confusion.

**EDIT**
After a suggestion from Torek code looks like below,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    input, err := os.Open("test.json")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    concurrency := 20
    inGest := make(chan []helpers.Order)
    ret := make(chan map[string]int)
    wg.Add(concurrency)
    for x := 0; x < concurrency; x++ {
        go processRecipesWorker(inGest, ret)
    }

    go ParseInMemory(input, inGest)

    go (func(wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ret)
    })(&wg)

    finalMap := make(map[string]int)
    for v := range ret {
        // Combine all incoming results
        for recipe, occurrence := range v {
            if v, ok := finalMap[recipe]; ok {
                finalMap[recipe] = occurrence + v
            } else {
                finalMap[recipe] = occurrence
            }
        }
    }

    //Further processing on finalMap

}

func ParseInMemory(input *os.File, ingest chan []Order) {
    data, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(input)
    var orders []Order

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &orders); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
    }

    batch := 100000
    for i := 0; i < len(orders); i += batch {
        j := i + batch
        if j > len(orders) {
            j = len(orders)
        }
        ingest <- orders[i:j]
    }
    close(ingest)
}

func processRecipesWorker(in <-chan []helpers.Order, r chan map[string]int) {
    // This will get us unique recipes and there occurrences
    // FR- 1 & 2 completed
    result := make(map[string]int)
    for _, order := range <-in {
        if v, ok := result[order.Recipe]; ok {
            result[order.Recipe] = v + 1
        } else {
            result[order.Recipe] = 1
        }
    }
    r <- result
    defer wg.Done()
}
```

Now the code is not throwing deadlock but it is only processing 2M records when I have 10M records I know it is happening because of all routines calling Done() so it gets ended. But Now the question is when should I call `wg.Done()` as how should code will know the last batch is processing and we can call the `.Done()` on that.

Comment: The general rule is "close the channel when there is nothing left to write to it". That's what you do with your `ingest` channel, but of course, there, it's *easy* to know when there is nothing left to write to it, as there is only the one writer. The `ret` channel has a problem: there are `concurrency` workers working on it. So, how do you close it when done writing? You need to have the *last* writer tell someone/something that he's done. But which one is *last?* Enter `sync.WaitGroup`...

Comment: The `sync.WaitGroup` entity lets you create a waitgroup, `wg`, to which you add 1 repeatedly (or some known value such as `concurrency` once up front). Then you spin off workers. When each worker is done, he calls `wg.Done()`. Then you spin off one more goroutine, that just calls `wg.Wait()` followed by `close(channel)`. The `wg.Wait()` waits for all the workers to have called `Done()` (the count goes to zero at that point, and `wg.Wait()` returns). That indicates that no one else is writing, so now you have this final goroutine close the channel.

Comment: @torek I tried using `WaitGroup()` but the problem is when should my worker call `.Done()` as my batches can be more than my `concurrency` number. The call to to `.Done()` is causing partial data processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close now:

```
for _, order := range <-in {
    ...
}
```

is wrong.  This receives one batch and loops through it, but you want to loop through all received batches, then loop through each one:

```
for batch := range in {
    for _, order := range batch {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup found the problem while debugging. Thanks for the help. Do you recommend anything to read on for concurrency? (i know a lot of material available but gets confusing what to look at.)

Comment: The various Go Blog items on concurrency are good. I don't have the links handy, but they should turn up with a google search.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example, where you know the number of goroutines that you want to start, you can do this without the `WaitGroup` approach.

[Here](https://play.golang.org/p/4HiufqiwAZC) you can find an example of a modification of your code, where I have omitted the part where you read from the file, just for the sake of brevity.

It boils down to two main modifications. First, you need an additional channel (in my example, it is called `quit`) to track when each goroutine is finished with work. Also, a counter for finished goroutines (`doneJobs` in the example).
So, your `processRecipesWorker` method should look like this:

```
func processRecipesWorker(in <-chan []Order, r chan map[string]int, quit chan<- int) {
 result := make(map[string]int)
 for orders := range in {
  for _, order := range orders {  
   if v, ok := result[order.Recipe]; ok {
        result[order.Recipe] = v + 1
    } else {
        result[order.Recipe] = 1
    }
    }
 }
 r <- result
 quit <- 1
}
```

Second, you can use a `for-select` loop, with a label to go through the data that is sent to `ret` and `quit` channels.

```
loop:
for{
  select {

    case v := <- ret:
      // Combine all incoming results
      for recipe, occurrence := range v {
        if v, ok := finalMap[recipe]; ok {
            finalMap[recipe] = occurrence + v
        } else {
            finalMap[recipe] = occurrence
        }
      }
    case <-quit:
      doneJobs++
      fmt.Println(doneJobs)
      if doneJobs >= concurrency {
       break loop
      }
  }
}
```

By using the `break loop` statement, you are able to break both from `select` and `for` loops.

In conclusion, @torek's solution with `WaitGroup` is a good one, it provides usage of general patterns used in Go. You can see that in [this](https://blog.golang.org/pipelines) article about Go pipelines, especially in the **fan-out fan-in** section. This answer just provides another way to run your program, without using the `WaitGroup` approach.